# Wrapping around array causing unexpected output in c

Tags: c, for-loop, cs50

I would expect that the values in the array would repeat in every 3rd character but I do not understand why to out put are different if they are referencing the same index.

Input:

> Command line argument: `baz`
>
> User input: `barfoo`
>
> Output: `caqmut`
>
> Expected output: `caqgon`

Values of `key_number[]` after first for loop:

```
key_number[0] = 1
key_number[1] = 0
key_number[2] = 25
key_number[3] = 32767
key_number[4] = 32
key_number[5] = 57
```

Code used:

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main(int argc, string argv[])
{   
    if(argc<=1)
    {
        printf("Usage: ./vigenere k");
        exit(1);
    }
    // convert command line input from string to int varible keyword
    string keyword = argv[1];

    //prompt user input and initialized
    printf("plaintext: ");
    string plaintext = get_string();
    printf("ciphertext: ");

    //create lower_case_array
    char lower_case[26] = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";

    //create upper_case_array
    char upper_case[26] = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";


    //convert key from string to int[]
    //int array_length =strlen(plaintext); 
    int key_number[6]; // [array_length]
    int key_length = strlen(keyword);
    //loop though key_number for the length of plaintext
    for (int i = 0;  i < (strlen(plaintext)); i++)
    {
        //if char is uppercase
        if (keyword[i] >= 65 && keyword[i] < 91 )
        {
            key_number[i] = (keyword[i % key_length]) - 65;   
        }
        // if char is lowercase
        else if (keyword[i] >= 97 && keyword[i] < 123)  
        {
            key_number[i] = (keyword[i % key_length]) - 97;  
        }
    }

    //print out letters accoring to ceasar cryptography
    for (int i = 0;  i < strlen(plaintext); i++)
    {
        //branch if letter is upper case
        if (plaintext[i] >= 65 && plaintext[i] < 91 )
        {
            printf("%c",  upper_case[((plaintext[i] - 65 + key_number[i]) % 26)]);    
        }
        //branch if letter is lower case
        else if (plaintext[i] >= 97 && plaintext[i] < 123)
        {
            printf("%c", lower_case[((plaintext[i] - 97 + key_number[i]) % 26)]);
        }
        //branch if any other character
        else
        {
            printf("%c", plaintext[i]);
        }
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

Comment: `if (keyword[i] >= 65 && keyword[i] < 91 )`: you're missin the modulo here. Store the value in a variable (with modulo) instead of pasting it 6 times in your code. You have undefined behaviour because you're reading out of bounds.

Comment: Time to step through with a debugger

Comment: @stark Yeah I did and I was watching how the array was getting populated. I still don't get how once i = 3 things get wacky. Everything stays the same

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Thanks. I didn't think about that. I'll experiment with that

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre That was it exactly! Thank you so much

Comment: @AndyC so let me post that as an answer.

Comment: `char lower_case[26] = "..."` can be simply initialized as `char lower_case[] = "..."` to avoid writing beyond the array bounds if you have an inadvertent extra character. Your initialization is fine, it's just prone to invoking *Undefined Behavior* if your count is short...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

what puzzled me when I read your code is that you're using `keyword[i % key_length]` sometimes and sometimes `keyword[i]`.

So when you're using `i`, you can go past the `keyword` table: undefined behaviour because `plaintext` is probably longer than `keyword`

You could have avoided that by rewriting your code more cleanly:

```
for (int i = 0;  i < (strlen(plaintext)); i++)
{
    char kc = keyword[i % key_length];
    //if char is uppercase
    if (kc >= 'A' && kc <= 'Z' ) // aka isupper(kc)
    {
        key_number[i] = kc - 'A';   
    }
    // if char is lowercase
    else if (kc >= 'a' && kc <= 'z')  // aka islower(kc)
    {
        key_number[i] = kc - 'a';  
    }
}
```

Comment: Curious, why `kc < ('Z'+1)` and not `kc <=  'Z'`?

Comment: because I like complicated. Edited, that's better, agreed. I suppose we could also use `isupper` and `islower` instead.

Comment: Nothing wrong with complicated, and nothing wrong with `else if (kc >= 'a' && kc <= 'z')`, but I've always liked to form the equality so it is more clear (at least in my jumbled mind) that `kc` lies within the boundaries used, e.g. `else if ('a' <= kc && kc <= 'z')`. Nothing wrong with either, but easier for some to see in the second form.